# Get Data from Javascript codes with Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrape

I am trying to get javascript data from website with Selenium. However, I could not achieve what I wanted. Below is a screenshot of the javascript code. I want to extract Barcode numbers and variation values (such as 36 numbers, 37 numbers) among these codes. How can I best do this? Thanks for your help.

[Web page javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtLcM.png)

EDIT 1:

Javascript Code:

window.**PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE**={"product":{"attributes":[],"alternativeVariants":[],"variants":[{"attributeId":338,"attributeName":"Beden","attributeType":"Size","attributeValue":"36","stamps":[{"type":1,"text":"KARGO BEDAVA"},{"type":3,"text":"%35"}],"price":{"profitMargin":0,"discountedPrice":{"text":"143,99 TL","value":143.99},"sellingPrice":{"text":"159,99 TL","value":159.99},"originalPrice":{"text":"219,99 TL","value":219.99},"currency":"TRY"},"fulfilmentType":"mp","attributeBeautifiedValue":"36","isWinner":true,"listingId":"cb32c614f54395f199628ef7066ab102","stock":null,"sellable":true,"availableForClaim":true,"barcode":"100406115","itemNumber":118134976,"discountedPriceInfo":"Sepette %10 İndirim","hasCollectable":false,"unitInfo":{"unitPrice":false,"unitPriceText":false},"rushDeliveryMerchantListingExist":false}],"otherMerchants":[],"campaign":{"id":591963,"name":"Kadın Giyimde Avantajlı Ürünler - Sepette %10 İndirim","startDate":"2021-11-30T14:30:05","endDate":"2021-12-07T05:00:00","isMultipleSupplied":false,"stockTypeId":7,"url":"/kadin-giyimde-avantajli-urunler---sepette--10-indirim/butikdetay/591963","showTimer":false},"category":{"id":103718,"name":"Klasik Topuklu Ayakkabı","hierarchy":"Ayakkabı/Topuklu Ayakkabı/Klasik Topuklu Ayakkabı","refundable":true,"beautifiedName":"klasik-topuklu-ayakkabi","isVASEnabled":false},"brand":{"isVirtual":false,"beautifiedName":"laminta","id":205748,"name":"LAMİNTA","path":"/laminta-x-b205748"},"color":"GÜMÜŞ ŞEFFAF","metaBrand":{"id":205748,"name":"LAMİNTA","beautifiedName":"","isVirtual":false,"path":""},"showVariants":true,"showSexualContent":true,"brandCategoryBanners":[],"allVariants":[{"itemNumber":118134976,"value":"36","inStock":true,"currency":"TRY","barcode":"100406115","price":143.99},{"itemNumber":118134979,"value":"37","inStock":true,"currency":"TRY","barcode":"100406116","price":143.99},{"itemNumber":118134975,"value":"38","inStock":true,"currency":"TRY","barcode":"100406117","price":143.99},{"itemNumber":118134983,"value":"39","inStock":true,"currency":"TRY","barcode":"100406118","price":143.99},{"itemNumber":118123516,"value":"40","inStock":true,"currency":"TRY","barcode":"100406119","price":143.99}]

My simple code is as follows. I am getting a single barcode with the code below. However, I cannot pull barcodes and other information for each variation.

```
def barkodBul():
    if ('barcode' in driver.page_source):
        p_id = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")
        for script in p_id:
            innerHTML = script.get_property('innerHTML')
            task = re.search('barcode', innerHTML)
            if (task):
                barkod = [l for l in innerHTML.split("{") if "barcode" in l][0]
                barkod = barkod.split(",")
                for k in range(0,len(barkod)):
                    if('barcode' in barkod[k]):
                        barkod = barkod[k].split(":")
                        print barkod[1]
                        barkod = barkod[1].replace('"', '')
                        print barkod
                        return barkod

    return 0
```

What I want to do:
36 BarcodeFor36
37 BarcodeFor37 etc.

EDIT 2 - Solution: Thanks [esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew)

```
def barkodBul2():

    time.sleep(3)
    timeout = 30
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pr-new-br")))
    product_detail = driver.execute_script('return window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__')
    for variant in product_detail['product']['variants']:
        print variant['attributeValue'] + " " + variant['barcode']

Output:
36 100406115
37 100406116
38 100406117
39 100406118
40 100406119
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use RegExp for this when the data is nicely structured as an Object? Extract the contents directly with Selenium, then access the data you want from there:

```
def barkodBul():
    product_detail = driver.execute_script('return window.PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE'))
    for variant in product_detail['product']['allVariants']:
        print variant['value'] + " " + variant['barcode']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help. I am using Python 2.7. And I'm getting this error.
for variant in product_detail['product']['allVariants']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: When are you calling `barkodBul()`? Have you waited for the page to be ready/fully loaded?

Comment: Yes. Waiting for the page to load. I also added more waits with time.sleep. However, the error persists. When I print the product_detail variable, it shows None.